# Struts ActionProxy: how to set a method?

Tags: java, struts2, junit, struts, opensymphony

I'm using openSymphony 2.1.2 and I have some old code that was written for older versions of openSymphony.

As you can see, it tells me that `ActionProxy` has no method `setMethod(String)`.
It probably [used to have](http://www.opensymphony.com/xwork/api/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionProxy.html#setMethod%28java.lang.String%29). But [not anymore](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/opensymphony/xwork/2.1.2/xwork-2.1.2-javadoc.jar!/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionProxy.html).

But it still has a method `String getMethod()`. So how is there a method variable that I can get, but not set? How do I set the method in the new API?

```
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionProxy;

protected ActionProxy proxy = null;

//used to work with older versions of openSymphony, now there's a compilation error here:
//The method setMethod(String) is undefined for the type ActionProxy
proxy.setMethod(methodName);
```

**UPDATE:**

I am working on a system (which was not written by me) that uses openSymphony 2.1. and Struts 2.3.8.

On that system, I am trying to apply the following code:

[Action Unit Testing with Struts 2.0. Part 2](http://www.lischke-online.de/index.php/java/action-unit-testing-with-struts-2-0-part-2)

That code fails with the versions of openSymphony and Struts my project uses. So I am trying to upgrade that code to the newer versions of openSymphony and Struts.

I need it in order to be able to simulate running the struts actions from my system, in a system that is based on a different framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DefaultActionProxy` is implementing `ActionProxy`. To set the `method` attribute you should extend `DefaultActionProxy` and set the super protected attribute via your `setMethod` implementation.

Then you should extend `DefaultActionProxyFactory` and substitute `DefaultActionProxy` in the `createActionProxy()`.

After that modify `struts.xml` and override

```
<bean type="com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionProxyFactory" name="xwork" ... />
```

with your own factory.

But preferably to set the method in the parameters with the `method:` prefix or using `setMethod` in the `ActionMapping` class that you could get from the `ActionContext` or you can extend the `DefaultActionMapper` to get the mapping you need. See [docs](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/action-mapper.html).

Comment: Thank you. But I wasn't able to understand what you meant by the last paragraph ("But preferably..."). I do not have a lot of experience with Struts. Could you please demonstrate your intention by some sample code?

Comment: I don't understand what are you doing and why do you need that `setMethod` to keep with the new API? Why not to use old one with your environment?

Comment: I have added an update above to explain what I am trying to do.

Comment: `ActionProxyFactory` has the `methodName` parameter in the `createActionProxy` method that you can use instead of `proxy.setMethod()`.

Comment: Thank you, that's even easier.

Answer (score 0):

Just use appropriate `createActionProxy` method of `ActionProxyFactory` which takes `methodName` as one of the parameters.

```
public ActionProxy createActionProxy(String namespace, String actionName,
    String methodName, Map<String, Object> extraContext, boolean executeResult,
    boolean cleanupContext);
```

or

```
public ActionProxy createActionProxy(String namespace, String actionName,
    String methodName, Map<String, Object> extraContext);
```

or

```
public ActionProxy createActionProxy(ActionInvocation actionInvocation,
    String namespace, String actionName, String methodName,
    boolean executeResult, boolean cleanupContext);
```

See: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/struts/struts2/tags/STRUTS_2_3_8/xwork-core/src/main/java/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionProxyFactory.java?view=markup